# Jquery Click Event is Not firing for Span

Tags: jquery, html

The click event is not triggering either for the span or the `<i>` when I move the id to the `<i>` tag.

```js
$("body").on("click", "#btnClear", function() {
  alert("Clicked");
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
  <span title="Tüm Liste" style="cursor: pointer;" class="input-group-addon" id="btnClear"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-home"></i></span>
  <input type="text" class="form-control" id="txtSearch" placeholder="GTIP KOD veya Ürün Adı" aria-describedby="basic-addon2">
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you guys I figured out what the issue was.

The event was placed wrongly inside another event.

Thank you all for your help.

Answer (score 2):

I think your code is working. There is no issue except, you have forgot to load `jquery`

```js
$("body").on("click", "#btnClear", function() {
  alert("Clicked");
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
  <span title="Tüm Liste" style="cursor: pointer;" class="input-group-addon" id="btnClear">ICON HERE.. CLICK</span>
  <input type="text" class="form-control" id="txtSearch" placeholder="GTIP KOD veya Ürün Adı" aria-describedby="basic-addon2">
</div>
```

I do not have `icon` to show there so I have placed a text to click there.

Hope its helped.

Comment: I made sure that the Jquery is loaded. The event works when I write some characters in the **txtSearch** text input.

Comment: @MohamedAl-ashrafKhalidAlfee: can you make a fiddle with your code & loaded script. Is you icon showing in span.

Comment: As @Dhaval Jardosh explain, you issue may be because of missing icon. And you are not able to click on `span` tag.

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```js
$("body").delegate("#btnClear", "click", function () {
    alert("Clicked");
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<div class="input-group">
   <span title="Tüm Liste" style="cursor: pointer;" class="input-group-addon" id="btnClear">
   <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-home"></i>
   </span>
   <input type="text" class="form-control" id="txtSearch" placeholder="GTIP KOD veya Ürün Adı" aria-describedby="basic-addon2">
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your span is not being displayed, that's the issue.

You JS is working fine. I gave border to your span.

```js
$("body").on("click", "#btnClear", function() {
  alert("Clicked");
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<link href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

<div class="input-group">

  <span title="Tüm Liste" style="cursor: pointer; min-width:40px;" class="input-group-addo" id="btnClear"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-home"></i></span>
  <input type="text" class="form-control" id="txtSearch" placeholder="GTIP KOD veya Ürün Adı" aria-describedby="basic-addon2">
</div>
```

Comment: The event works when I write characters in the **txtSearch** text input.

Comment: So you mean when you place icon in it, that's when it's not working.right?

Comment: I removed the icon. same problem. :/